# Как можно сделать фокус на определенном элементе по сочетаниию клавиш?

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, есть Окно и в нем различные элементы. Как я могу сделать так, что бы по сочетанию клавиш я могу, например, перепрыгнуть на DataGrid, а по другому в какой-нибудь TextBox и т д...

Comment: А разве нельзя добавить обработчик KeyDown на окно в WPF и в нём обрабатывать сочетания клавиш? `Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { if (e.Key == Key.F5) { this.Title = "You pressed F5"; } }`

Comment: Ну это нарушет MVVM...

Comment: Вы можете вызвать команду `<Window.InputBindings><KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+F" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/></Window.InputBindings>` А в коде команды уже работать с фокусом.

Comment: Не думал, что фокус на элементе относится к MVVM... Скорее всего мне далеко ещё до MVVM... Так получается, что для переключения фокуса элементов табом, тоже нужно команды городить?

Comment: @XelaNimed Это не нарушает MVVM, так как в обработчике идет работа с контролами, а не с данными. То есть нет взаимодействия с вьюмоделью. Но кодбихайнд для этой задачи писать совсем не обязательно. А для переключения табом есть `TabIndex` на контролах.

Comment: @aepot ну это получается, что нужно сам элемент пробрасывать в VM?

Comment: @aepot извиняюсь, затупил :) В этом случае, как мне кажется, нужно поправить вопрос и его заголовок указав нём, что это относится к XAML.

Comment: Поищите способ прибиндить фокус. Есть вменяемые решения, но их много разных, хитрых и не очень. Подберите то, которое вам подходит. [Вот например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356781/12888024).

Comment: @aepot самым простым кажется DataTrigger, но что-то не нашел способа его красиво сбиндить, так как получается, что я должен сначала присвоить True, уведомить, получить фокус, присвоить False, уведомить, чтобы перефокус работал...

Comment: Фокус снимается автоматически. По сути нужно научиться только закидывать в него `true`, остальное окно само сделает. `DataTrigger` не прокатит, потому что свойство `IsFocused` [не имеет сеттера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.isfocused?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Другими словами, чтобы на элемент интерфейса воткнуть фокус, нужно вызвать `elem.Focus()`, больше никак (ну если не рефлексировать).

Comment: А в чём проблема с code-behind? Это ж чисто вьюшная задача. Хорошо, если получается на чистом XAML'е, но если в разметке не выходит — code-behind именно для решения вьюшных задач и предназначен.

Comment: MVVM это не про то что нельзя в кодбихайнд. MVVM это по разделение ответственности. Если кодбихайнд получается короче и лаконичнее, чем вы сделаете это в XAML, то я всеми руками за кодбихайнд

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Ну да, но это ж чисто задача уровня отображения, MVVM тут не играет потому, что всё происходит в пределах одного слоя.

Answer (score 3):

Да легко. Например, [так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label.target?view=net-5.0):

```xaml
<Label Grid.Row="0" Target="{Binding ElementName=SourceArea}">_Source:</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="SourceArea"/>

<Label Grid.Row="2" Target="{Binding ElementName=DestinationArea}">_Destination:</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="DestinationArea"/>
```

Получается вот как (нажимаю <kbd>Alt + S</kbd> и <kbd>Alt + D</kbd> для перехода):

[image: старая гвардия борозды не испортит]

Так же можно устанавливать shortcut на другие контролы, например, на кнопку (`<Button>_Go</Button>` будет реагировать на <kbd>Alt + G</kbd>), меню (пункт `<MenuItem Header="_File">` будет активизирован по нажатию <kbd>Alt + F</kbd>) и т. д.

---

Заметьте, что Майкрософт <s>предписывает</s> рекомендует использовать в UI комбинации с Alt для access keys (то есть, для клавиатурной навигации), а комбинации с Ctrl — для shortcut keys (то есть, для непосредственного вызова команд).

Литература:

- Style guide для «современных приложений» (то есть UWP) — [Access keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/access-keys)
- Style guide для приложений Win32 (то есть Windows Desktop) — [Keyboard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/inter-keyboard)
- [Guidelines for Keyboard User Interface Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dnacc/guidelines-for-keyboard-user-interface-design#creating-shortcut-keys-and-access-keys)

Comment: А если лейбл кириллический?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Работает точно так же, а что?

Comment: А если я не хочу, чтобы какой-то контрол имел лейбл? Я пробовал лейбл делать невидимым, но навигация пропадает=(

Comment: Еще проблема в том, что если какие-то лейблы начинаются на одну и туже букву...

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну так вы же можете влейбле любую букву сделать хоткеем, не обязательно первую

Comment: Ну, если сделать label невидимым не с помощью Visibility = Collapsed, а с помощью Width = 0, то работает. Ещё должно работать `AccessKeyManager.Register` в code-behind, но у меня почему-то не выходит.

Answer (score 3):

Если не хотите завязываться на стандартные сочетания <kbd>Alt + Letter</kbd>, предложенные в соседнем ответе, можно пойти дальше и задействовать фичу `InputBindings`.

Эта фича работает с командами, поэтому выполняемое действие придется оформить в этом виде. Это будет команда чисто для View слоя и я выношу ее в отдельный статический класс, для того, чтобы можно было ее переиспользовать к разных View:

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static ICommand FocusControl { get; } = new DelegateCommand<UIElement>(e => e.Focus());
}
```

<sub>Используйте любую реализацию команды, которая у вас есть</sub>

<sub>Если статический класс не нравится, можно сделать его не статическим и создавать экземпляр, например, в ресурсах вашего контейнера</sub>

Теперь в разметке необходимо привязать эту команду к верхнеуровневому контейнеру (у меня это окно), в параметре команда получает элемент, на котором необходимо сфокусироваться, поэтому придется задать контролам имена:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding
        Key="B" Modifiers="Alt"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static c:Commands.FocusControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Button}" />
    
    <KeyBinding
        Key="T" Modifiers="Ctrl"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static c:Commands.FocusControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TextBox}" />
    
    <KeyBinding
        Key="C" Modifiers="Shift"
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static c:Commands.FocusControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox}" />

    <KeyBinding
        Key="X" Modifiers=""
        Command="{Binding Source={x:Static c:Commands.FocusControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox}" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<StackPanel Margin="5">
    <Button Name="Button" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>

    <TextBox Name="TextBox" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>

    <ComboBox Name="ComboBox" IsEditable="True" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>

    <CheckBox Name="CheckBox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Всё!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только обратите внимание, что некоторые сочетания клавиш перехватываются на уровне ОС, поэтому могут не сработать (в основном это все сочетания с <kbd>Windows</kbd>), также некоторые сочетания могут перехватываться контролом, поэтому не провалятся до контейнера верхнего уровня (это, например, <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> в `TextBox` и т. п.), ну и нужно быть осторожным с сочетаниями без модификатора (например, как сделано здесь, вы не сможете ввести букву `X` в окна ввода, т. к. она будет перехвачена).

Comment: Прикольное решение, так как сочетания клавиш будут прописаны в XAML вместе с другими VM командами, а не в коде захардкожены.

Comment: @Андрей NOP: Хм, ну можно и вручную прописать, но Майкрософт рекомендует для навигации именно Alt (дописал в ответе ссылки на UI Guidelines). Поэтому и их фреймворк заточен под Alt ([`AccessText`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.accesstext?view=net-5.0), вот это всё).

Comment: @VladD, ну это мне понятно, эти хоткеи, Alt+"Буква из команды" ещё с первых версий винды как стандартное решение (они там даже специально по нажатию Alt подсвечиваются) и в целом я согласен, что для одинаковых действий в разных приложениях должны использоваться одинаковые хоткеи. Но если тс нужно альтернативное что-то, то как вариант, почему нет?

Comment: @Андрей NOP: Я не критикую, я просто обращаю внимание читателей, что стандартное решение достигается меньшими усилиями. А если хочется нестандартного, добро пожаловать в InputBindings.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вопрос "для общего развития", а можно ли иметь класс комманд с зависимостями, а потом создать экземпляр в ресурсах окна и чтобы DI его как-то разрезолвил?

Comment: @iluxa1810, не, wpf так не умеет, в ресурсах экземпляры создаются самим wpf и только через конструктор без параметров. Если хотите внедрять зависимости, выход только один — внедрять их в конструктор окна, ну и это только кодбихайнд, в XAML такого не сделать

Comment: А если я внедрю в конструктор окна экземпляр класса-сервиса с кнопками, то на него получается я никак не смогу сослаться из Xaml? Только ручками его биндить?

Comment: @iluxa1810, можно, почему нет, выставляете в публичное свойство и биндите обычным способом, например через `FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window`